# need next month and pre month in js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to pass month in function, from that month i need previous month and next month.

I have done ,

```
var month = "Fev_2017";
var preMonth = function(month){
 var pre = moment().subtract(1, month)
console.log(pre); // its showing Jan_2017
}
var nextmonth = function(month){
 var pre = moment().add(1, month)
console.log(pre); // its showing Jan_2017
}
```

can any one help me please, where have I done wrong?

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation of [`.add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`.subtract()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: try `var pre = moment(month).add(1, 'months')`

Comment: in addition to being wrong for moment, `var month = Fev_2017` is a syntax error.

Comment: `var month = Fev_2017` is not valid Javascript unless `Fev_2017` is a variable.